# ASP.NET 3.5 on Windows 2000

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I am trying to get an ASP.NET 3.5 site to run on a Windows 2000 machine (not my idea!!!) but am having some problems. I have been working through copying required DLL files from `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5` into my app bin directory. This succesfully got me past the "assembly not found" errors.

However, I am now getting the following error.

> Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found"

How can I fix this? It is primarily LINQ functionality I am looking to utilise.

Comment: Either keep hitting the brick wall or buy a ladder. In your case, keep smashing your head against Windows 2000 or demand that this system is upgraded to something that can support .NET 3.5...

Comment: Im in the same boat... wish there was a workaround -- have 40 servers to upgrade to 3.5, 20 of them are 2000 server.   I'm going the other route (even someone said it below). I hacked VPC2007 install to install on 2000 server, and going to run 2003 server as a VM on it.

Answer (score 10):

You are going to have many issues as [.NET 3.5 is not supported on Windows 2000 (see **System Requirements**)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en).

Comment: Indeed not, however .net 3.5 is essentially .net with extra dlls. I really only need LINQ functionality. See eg http://rainstorms.me.uk/blog/2009/04/22/more-details-on-installing-net-35-in-windows-2000/

Comment: You are mostly correct but it is a bit more complicated then that (take for instance the fact that your most recent error is due to missing the C# compiler).  My point is that you are trying to do something unsupported.  Unsupported endeavors often work but you may be creating bigger problems for yourself that you haven't even seen yet.  I would suggest that a better route would be to bite the bullet and upgrade the OS.  That being said, I am not you nor do I understand your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install .NET Framework 3.5 manually. It relies on .NET 2.0 runtime + some extra stuff.

- See [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 in
  Windows
  2000](http://rainstorms.me.uk/blog/2008/03/12/microsoft-net-framework-35-in-windows-2000/)
  for **install steps**.
- See also [More details on installing
  .NET 3.5 in Windows
  2000](http://rainstorms.me.uk/blog/2009/04/22/more-details-on-installing-net-35-in-windows-2000/)
  for **explanations**.

Answer (score 1):

Install a Virtual Machine with a newer Windows in it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Many 3.5 sites will work just fine in 2.0, you just need to compile them that way. I would have whoever built the app switch to 2.0 targets and see how it goes. If that doesn't take, the VM option is probably the best way to fly.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some time and pain, install on a platform that supports 3.5.

Trying to circumvent minimum requirements usually comes back to bite you in the end.

Just because you can doesn't always mean you should. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not in control of the hardware, or budget for hardware for these peeps! Otherwise, I agree!

Answer (score 0):

Unfamiliar with the environment, but...

More of the framework (including csc.exe) resides in %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 (e.g. C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5) - are these files on your installation and the directory in your path?